# Catch events javascript in swift

Tags: javascript, android, ios, swift

In android i use  this

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface

to catch the events javascript in java

but in swift, what can i use ?

i just found to execute javascript for swift, but i want catch a click event.

Example, when the user click in button, change the screen according the option selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WKWebView for this

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
contentController.add(self, name: scriptMessageName)

let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.userContentController = contentController
let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
```

Then confirm you ViewController to WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate

```
extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

        switch message.name {
        case scriptMessageName:
            someAction() 
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```